# debug app works fine but signed release is only showing first screen (react native)

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on my 1st project and the app works fine in the emulator but when I install the released apk it always get stuck on the first screen and doesn't navigate to the next page (tried with setTimout for automatic and tried TouchableOpacity(it makes the press effect but no navigation) none worked). I didn't know the cause of this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend that you check logs with https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat first.
If you provide logs, I might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by installing properly Reanimated
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.2.0/installation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).